# Solve $\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n=10$ without using estimation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n=10,$$
where $e$ is Euler's number.

I am unsure how to solve this problem. Do I take the $\log$ of $10$?

I have estimated it to be around $4.525$.

Comment: $(x/e)^x=10$ looks better, since $n$ usually is a positive integer.

Comment: I was under the impression that you could right it in terms of e. Consider a simplification $$n^n=10$$ could that be simplified?

Comment: My guess is that you can only solve this numerically

Comment: I also thought that

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x^x e^{-x}$ so $f'/f=(x\ln x-x)'=\ln x$. The Newton-Raphson method gives an iteration of the form $x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{1-10(e/x_n)^{x_n}}{\ln x_n}$. Start with $x_0=5$.

Comment: Without estimation ? ... I the Lambert $W$ function is required ?

Comment: Lambert $W$ is more trouble than it's worth in practice, and its computation uses either this kind of trick or a power series anyway, and I don't think noticing an integer so far from the root counts as estimation.

Answer (score 2):

Take logarithms and divide by $e$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{n}{e} \ln( \frac{n}{e}) =\frac{\ln(10)}{e} \\
e^{\ln(n/e)}  \ln( \frac{n}{e}) =\frac{\ln(10)}{e} \\
\ln(n/e)=W(\ln(10)/e) \\
n=e^{1+W(\ln(10)/e)} = 4.52 \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
where $W$ is the Lambert function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function. It can be evaluated using Wolfie https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%7B1%2BProductLog(ln(10)%2Fe)%7D

Comment: If the question is from a class, and this is the expected answer, I would a bit annoyed if I were taking the class, since the "solution" seems to be pretty much just finding the name "Lambert function", rather than actually any mathematical understanding. Q: "How do you find an x such that foo of x is 10?" A: "Take the bar of 10, where 'bar' is defined as 'foo inverse' ". Blegh.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to solve this numerically is to rearrange the equation $$\left(\frac xe\right)^x=10$$ into the iterative sequence $$x_{n+1}=e\times10^{\frac{1}{x_n}}$$ and start with $$x_1=4$$

After a few steps you get $$x\simeq4.522724579...$$

Comment: That's estimation, and applying this rigorously would require showing that this converges.